# Javascript won't fire

Tags: javascript

I have been messing with this code for a bit too long now, so I thought I'd apply for some help...
This just don't work at all for me. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?
Any advice appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bad Math (typeConv)</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Doing bad math... will she run??</h1>
<button type="button" onclick="addWrong()">addWrong</button>
<button type="button" onclick="sayHi()">sayHi</button>

<script>    
function addWrong() {
    var x = prompt("X?");
    var y = prompt("Y?");

    var sum = x + y;

    alert(x " + " y " = " + sum);
    } // end addWrong

function sayHi() {
    alert("Hi");
}   
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `alert(x " + "
            y " = " + sum);` bad bad syntax - check your developer tools console next time ... should be `alert(x + " + " + y + " = " + sum);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your "alert" call inside your "addWrong" function, you aren't doing the string concatenation correctly.

The plus' go around the variables, outside of the string quotes:
`alert(x + " + " + y + " = " + sum);`

Just a little mix up of the quotes.

Comment: or rather `alert(x + ' + ' + y + ' = ' + sum)`

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on string interpolation (using variables inside of strings). There are two problems with your code:

```
alert(x " + " y " = " + sum);
```

x and y are defined variables, and are being evaluated alongside strings without any sort of operators indicating how you want them to interact. This is the same thing as typing x"r"y"z", which would also error out. You could write it as:

```
alert(x + " + " + y + " = " + sum);
```

But that is pretty confusing to read. See below for my suggestion.

The other problem is how you are adding the inputs from prompt("X?") and prompt("Y?").

```
var x = prompt("X?");
```

No matter what the user answers, it will be coerced into a string. And when you add two strings together, the '+' operator is used to concatenate the strings, instead of add them together (as integers). So you would need to convert the inputs into an integer. There are better ways to account for edge cases, but the simplest way is to call parseInt() around X and Y:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bad Math (typeConv)</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Doing bad math... will she run??</h1>
<button type="button" onclick="addWrong()">addWrong</button>
<button type="button" onclick="sayHi()">sayHi</button>

<script>    
function addWrong() {
    var x = prompt("X?");
    var y = prompt("Y?");

    var sum = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y);

    alert(`${x} + ${y} = ${sum}`);
    } // end addWrong

function sayHi() {
    alert("Hi");
}   
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick, helpful and in-depth responses all.

Comment: I was starting to go cross-eyed